# C Programming. Comparing an array's contents.

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcmp

I have an array as result of my program's input:

//1.

```
int i, numberOfOccurances;

   for(i = 0; i < numOfOccurrances; i++) {
      printf("%d",PrintOccurrances[i]);
   }
```

and as an example output:

```
121
```

Now I want to compare this array so that I can print an additional statement, for example:

//2.

```
if (PrintOccurrances == 121) {
    printf("This means blah");
} else if (PrintOccurrances == 232) {
    printf("This means something else");
}
```

//what type of variable should i set and HOW should I set it at point 1?
//what type of string statement should I have at point 2.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Concatenate the value to a string and use strcmp.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  At the moment, you've not really provided enough information for use to be able to give you a good answer.  What type is the base type for the array (`char`, `int`, `double`)?  Are you comparing the array with itself, or with another array?  What are the semantics of the array?  Is it ordered?  Are duplicates allowed? There are more questions that will arise depending on the answers to these.  Ultimately, what is your goal — what is the human comprehensible statement of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I note that in fragment `//1.`, your variable `PrintOccurances` is an array, but in fragment `//2.`, your variable of the same name is a scalar, not an array.  This adds to the difficulty of interpreting your requirements.  (There are no a's in 'occurrences' either, but that's a very minor issue.)

Answer (score 1):

Make a comparison function and use compound literals at the call site:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool int_arr_cmp_n(int const * a, int const * b, size_t len)
{
    while (len--)
        if (*a++ != *b++)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (int_arr_cmp_n(PrintOccurrances, (int[]){1,2,1}, 3)) { /* ... */ }
```